# How to create blank space in lightning-record-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

I am using a lightning-record-form to enable view and and edit.  I have specified a custom list of fields displayed in two columns.  The fields populate in the columns left to right and then top to bottom.  I need to specify some blank spaces in the layout, however, there does not seem to be a way to do this.  If I specify null or '' in the list of fields, it does not create a blank space or just totally breaks.  Any way to specify a blank space in the lightning-record-form layout without building up the page from scratch?

html:

```
<lightning-record-form
     record-id={recordId}
     object-api-name="SBQQ__Quote__c"
     fields={soldToFields2Cols}
     columns="2"
     mode="view"
</lightning-record-form>
```

js:

```
   @track soldToFields2Cols = [
    'SBQQ__Account__c',
    'Sold_To_Customer_Number__c',
    'Sold_To_Name_2__c',
    'Sold_To_Street__c',
    'Sold_To_Name_3__c',
    'Sold_To_Name_4_or_MS__c',
    'SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c',
    'Sold_To_City__c',
    'Sold_To_Email__c',
    'Sold_To_State__c',
    'Sold_To_Phone__c',
    'Sold_To_Zip__c',
    'Sold_To_Ext__c',
    'Sold_To_Country__c'
];
```

I've tried using '', null, and 'emptySpace' as entries in the soldToFields2Cols array, but none of those work.

Comment: Can you add here the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @rahulgawale.  Code has been added.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

No. You do not have any control over how [record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) renders.

> lightning-record-form is less customizable. To customize the form
>   layout or provide custom rendering of record data, use
>   lightning-record-edit-form (add or update a record) and
>   lightning-record-view-form (view a record).

Other points to note from doc:

1. To specify the field order, use fields without the layout-type attribute. We don't recommend using the fields attribute with the layout-type attribute as the display order of the fields can vary. Alternatively, use the lightning-record-edit-form or lightning-record-view-form component to display a custom layout.
2. lightning-record-form does not support prepopulating of field values when the form loads. To create a form that displays custom field values, use the lightning-record-edit-form component.  (implementing lightning:pageReferenceUtils and creating the object using lightning:navigation with the standard__object page type will open standard new record page with prepopulated values)

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.  So much more work just to add some blanks spaces in the layout.